# Upgrading Postgres from 32bit to 64bit version on Windows

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, 32bit-64bit

I could not find specific steps on how to properly do this. When I did a simple upgrade, I'm getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: expected "]" to end datum, but got "80}"; length = 4
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:254)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "simple upgrade". Describe what you did. Also: PostgreSQL version(s)? What windows version? The general procedure is: Use the 32-bit version's `pg_dump` to dump a copy of the database(s) and `pg_dumpall --globals-only` to dump the user roles, etc. Shut down and optionally uninstall the 32-bit version - there's no need to actually remove the database directory, though. Install the 64-bit version, start it, restore the globals dump with `psql` then restore the database dumps(s).

Comment: That was what I needed. I thought the upgrade is as simple as running the 64-bit installer without making any backups.

Comment: The 32-bit and 64-bit versions of PostgreSQL have different file formats, much as PostgreSQL has different file formats on different platforms and operating systems. While frustrating for data mobility this is a significant performance optimisation and code simplification. That's why you can't just install the 64-bit version and have it work - because the file format is different it has a different default datadir to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The general procedure is:

- Use the 32-bit version's `pg_dump` to dump a copy of the database(s) and `pg_dumpall --globals-only` to dump the user roles, etc
- Shut down and optionally uninstall the 32-bit version - there's no need to actually remove the database directory, though
- Install the 64-bit version and start it
- restore the globals dump with `psql` then restore the database dumps(s)

(Actually, a clarification - if the 64-bit version is also a newer PostgreSQL version than the 32-bit version you're upgrading from, you should install the newer version first then use the newer versions's `pg_dump` to dump the older version's database. The above only applies if the versions are the same and you're just converting to 64-bit).

Another thing to note is that there's often little point in upgrading from 32-bit to 64-bit. PostgreSQL uses a per-process model that means that each process can use (2GB - shared_buffers) RAM for its work on 32-bit Windows. This is typically sufficient for most tasks, since you can leave shared_buffers fairly small even on a system with tons of RAM and let the rest of the RAM be used as operating system disk cache. It's only an issue if you need huge `work_mem` for really big individual queries.

Comment: Just stumbled about the same problem here. Thanks to your explanation, I simply uninstalled 64bit PQSL and installed 32bit. Tried the same again...works :)

Comment: Just thought it's worth mentioning; I just used pg_dump from a PGv10 32-bit installation, dumping to -c "bak" files, installed PGv11 64-bit on the same server, and used the 64-bit installation's pg_restore to get the data moved over. No hiccups at all.

Comment: @Krummelz That's because you used `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`, so you did a logical dump/restore. An issue only arises if you try to start the 64-bit postgres directly against the 32-bit postgres's data directory or use a physical backup/restore like `pg_basebackup`. Also, what you did will only work if the 32-bit and 64-bit version coexist peacefully, which they used not to do on Windows due to clashes in service names.